# C# Regular expression - exclude underscores & spaces at beginning and end of text

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

I've been battling trying to get this regular expression to work.
I want the expression to display the error when a string contains space either at beginning or at the end of a strong (spaces in the middle are allowed). Also I would like to exclude underscore and hyphens.

This is what I have so far.

```
[RegularExpression(@"^.*\s*[-_]", ErrorMessage = "string cannot begin with or end with a space, or contain a hyphen or underscore")]
```

This doesnt work as expected, anyone know what I am missing to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```cs
[RegularExpression(@"^[^\s_-]+(?:\s+[^\s_-]+)*$", ErrorMessage = "string cannot begin with or end with a space, or contain a hyphen or underscore")]
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[^\s_-]+` - one or more chars other than whitespace, `_` and `-`
- `(?:\s+[^\s_-]+)*` - zero or more reptitions of:

  - `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
  - `[^\s_-]+` - one or more chars other than whitespace, `_` and `-`
- `$` - end of string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/x7MfMp/1).

Comment: Thanks wiktor, that does what I expect it to do! Much appreciated